# Position: Fixed is disabling my scroller in IE7

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-position

I have a three-column layout of three news scrollers (using Tiny Scrollbar http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/).

Business needs dictate that this page function in IE7. To further complicate things, each div contains an iFrame, as each of these scrollers had to be a separate HTML file. If I position the divs as relative, when a user clicks on the scrollbar to scroll, the entire frame shifts to the left a few pixels. Holding down and moving the mouse will move it side to side. When I position the divs as fixed, the frame stays in place but it's content (links, scrolling, etc.) are completely disabled.

I apologize in advance, I'm fairly new to these things and learning as I go. Any suggestions?

Comment: When I have understood your problem right, then it is an absolute normal behavior. When you put an element to position fixed then scrolling has no effect to it, because you have fixed it to a special point on the screen. On the other side, when your element overflows, it must makes some space for the scroll bars and shifts the content a bit. You can avoid that with showing the scroll bars at every time with overflow:scroll.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for clarifying, like I said I'm still learning so I appreciate it. -- So is there anything I can do to stop it from jogging to the left when positioned as relative?

Comment: yes you can add the style overflow:scroll; then the scroll bar is shown at every time and the content don't shifts. Or you must avoid scrolling completely with overflow:hidden; but that is not wanted I think.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that content shifts to left because browser's scrollbar appears. You can disable scrollbars of iframe. Add some style to iframe tag like the following:

```
<iframe style="overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
```

If it is not enough, add some attributes to the body tag of the page which is loaded into iframe like:

```
<body style="overflow:hidden;" scroll="no">
```